# How it works when Ar.js processes ImageDescriptor?

Tags: ar.js

I'm trying to make a system in which users freely add images and these images become NFT. I want to modify the a-nft tag in order to give ImageDescriptors separately but I'm in trouble.

Now, I accomplish to upload images, convert them to ImageDescriptors(.iset, .fset, .fset3), and save these file data on session storage (like ".iset":"hogehoge...", ".fset":"hugahuga...",...).

However, when I add a-nft tag depending on these uploaded ImageDescriptors, I have to give an URL of "the directory which contains all these ImageDescriptors", like that

```
<a-nft
        type="nft"
        url="The directory which contains all three ImageDescriptors"
        smooth="true"
        smoothCount="10"
        smoothTolerance=".01"
        smoothThreshold="5"
>
```

I want to give separated URL like

```
<a-nft
        type="nft"
        url_iset="hoge"
    url_fset="fuga"
    url_fset3="nyan"
        smooth="true"
        smoothCount="10"
        smoothTolerance=".01"
        smoothThreshold="5"
>
```

To solve the problem, I've searched AR.js src for 2 weeks. However, I cannot find any hints about "Why AR.js unity the URL", and "How the URL, namely ImageDescriptor is processed".

If someone knows how ImageDescriptors are processed or a better way to implement separated URLs, please let me know.